# Printing two separate scripts to the same console window

Tags: python, console, tkinter, call, subprocess

I'm writing a large series of automated tests in python and I would like to use a single master script with a gui to call which particular test I want to run.

I'm using subprocess.call(path, shell=True) where path is the location and name of the selected test. This works fine, but the console only outputs the print statements from my master script. Each of the automated tests also has an output that I want to view as the test is running.

Can I either print these outputs to the same console or force it to open up a new console window?

Edit 1: I suppose I should verify. As soon as the test script is launched, I don't really care about the output of the master script.

Edit 2: Here is the traceback error that occurs when I set shell=False

```
Exception in Tkinter callback 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1470, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "C:\Documents and Settings\CDM\Desktop\workspace\Master.py", line 50, in execute_test
call(path, shell=False)
File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 524, in call
return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 948, in _execute_child
startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Comment: I think you'll have to use a third script which receives both inputs, and proceed to your master script.

Comment: Your problem is the `shell=True`, why do you need that?

Comment: @Ccheese4 Add the traceback to the question, the important part is cut out.

Comment: It could be you just need `[sys.executable, 'C:/fred/hello.py']` (or similar) for your command.  `shell=True` is often only needed for file association.

Comment: It should print to the same console by default. You could use `subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, path])` to run in the same console. Or `subprocess.check_call("cmd /c start cmd /c".split() +[sys.executable, path])` to start in a new window.

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian That second one calls up the command window just fine. How does this portion work? "cmd /c start cmd /c".split()

Comment: It runs `cmd.exe` that starts another `cmd.exe`. You need the first one to call `start` command. The intent is to create a new console window.